# Ubuntu 20.04 in dual boot randomly shutting down however Windows doesn't

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, shutdown, battery

I have installed Ubuntu 20.04 in dual boot with Windows 10.
My Laptop specs are:

```
Lenovo Ideapad 520,  
Intel i5-8250u,  
Nvidia MX150.  
8gigs in dual channel (2666Mhz).
```

The problem only persists when I am running Ubuntu.

After shutting down it turns on only power button lights up and then turns off. I have disconnected and reconnected my battery as well and have tried without battery too.

Contrary to this windows runs smooth which concludes that there isn't any hardware issue. Please help. Thanks in advance.
EDIT: [Here](https://pastebin.com/C372uGun) is the link of the logs after running `sudo journalctl  -b -1 -e` .

Comment: Read  https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask and https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting

Comment: You can examine the shutdown logs with `sudo journalctl  -b -1 -e`. Read `man journalctl sudo`.

Comment: The logs show you're using `nouveau`, the open-source community driver for Nvidia. Your graphics need the Nvidia proprietary drivers, that should be all..